# After upgraded Sharepoint Foundation we have unicode/letter issues

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, upgrade, localization, encoding

So no need to pretend like I'm an expert cause I'm not.

We have a file management system we use for a lot of stuff that was developed for us a few years back, this is hosted on a Sharepoint Foundation 2013.

Now our hosting provider by mistake upgraded the Sharepoint instead of just the OS a week ago :(

Ever since they upgraded we have issues with our filemanagement system.
when users wants to attach files to their outlook they will come out as
text%20test#20text.xls instead of containing blank spaces.

Also whats worse is we live in Denmark which means we have the letters 'æ ø å' they are not translated correctly anymore, which means when the users try and download files with those letters, SharePoint says 'sorry that file mO#(/&"/(de dont exist.

Now I am in a pickle cause our hosting provider dont really know a lot about Sharepoint except they messed it up, blaming them won't get me anywhere.

Luckily I have a copy running of the old filemanagement version on another server.
But I cant see the difference (am hoping its just a sharepoint setting)
Danish is already included as alternative language, but I imagine thats not the problem, probably some unicode something.

I heard someone mention something about PS config tools, that has not been run, does that make sense to this problem?

Hoping someone can help me.
Regards

Comment: Can you give some more info on what "Upgraded SharePoint" entails?  This does not answer your question but SharePoint 2013 was the last to have a foundation version, so if you are now on SharePoint 2016 or 2019 you are gonna need server licenses and user CALs.  If "Upgraded SharePoint" means that they applied a new CU to SP 2013 then the farm may need to have the config wizard run on it to complete the CU install.  This will need to be run on each SP server in the farm one at a time.

Comment: You mentioned SP was upgraded by mistake. So do you have a "before upgrade" copy? If not, please ask the vendor what have they performed. SharePoint upgrade include various steps and it is not easy to "upgrade" by mistake. Do you mean the vendor "patched" it by mistake?